# Is operational really isomorphic to a free monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

#### Proofs

In [this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html) blog post, Tekmo makes the point that we can prove that `ExitSuccess` exits because (I presume) it's like the `Const` functor for that constructor (it doesn't carry the `x` so `fmap` behaves like `const`).

With the operational package, Tekmo's `TeletypeF` might be translated something like this:

```
data TeletypeI a where
    PutStrLn :: String -> TeletypeI ()
    GetLine :: TeletypeI String
    ExitSuccess :: TeletypeI ()
```

I've read that operational is isomorphic to a free monad, but can we prove here that `ExitSuccess` exits?  It seems to me that it suffers from exactly the same problem as `exitSuccess :: IO ()` does, and in particular if we were to write an interpreter for it, we'd need to write it like as if it didn't exit:

```
eval (ExitSuccess :>>= _) = exitSuccess
```

Compare to the free monad version which doesn't involve any pattern wildcard:

```
run (Free ExitSuccess) = exitSuccess
```

#### Laziness

In the [Operational Monad Tutorial](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html) apfelmus mentions a drawback:

> The state monad represented as s -> (a,s) can cope with some infinite
>   programs like
>
> ```
> evalState (sequence . repeat . state $ \s -> (s,s+1)) 0
> ```
>
> whereas the list of instructions approach has no hope of ever handling
>   that, since only the very last Return instruction can return values.

Is this true for free monads as well?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that something like `(:>>=)` is used for [the free monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#line-142)?

Comment: That example was for operational.

Comment: Note operational is effectively `Free (Coyoneda f)`, `Coyoneda f` is isomorphic to `f`, so `Free (Coyoneda f)` is isomorphic to `Free f`.

Comment: @EdwardKmett: I'm confused. I find that `Coyoneda Const a ~= Identity a`, which is not isomorphic to `Const a`.

Comment: `Coyoneda (Const m) a` is isomorphic to `Const m a` which is isomorphic to `m`.

Comment: If by Const you mean the trivial `data Foo a = Foo` functor then `Coyoneda Foo a = exists b. (b -> a, Foo)` which doesn't give you an extra element, since you don't have a `b` to call the function with.

Comment: @EdwardKmett Thanks! I meant the latter and now I see that I accidentally mixed up `exists` and `forall`.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus: That said, there is one sense in which Operational is larger in that `Free` is the monad generated by a `Functor`, when `f` is not a `Functor`, `Operational` and my Church-encoded `Free` monad and `Free (Codensity f)` are defined even if `Free f` is not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Allow me to scoop the grand prize by boldly combining the previous answers. ;-))

The key observation is this: Prove *what exactly*? The formulation in terms of `Free TeletypeF` allows us to prove the following:

> Every *interpreter* for programs of type `Free TeletypeF a` must exit when it encounters the `ExitSuccess` instruction. In other words, we automatically get the *algebraic law*
>
> ```
>  interpret (exitSuccess >>= k) = interpret exitSuccess
> ```

Thus, the `Free` monad actually allows you to bake certain algebraic laws into the type.

In contrast, the operational approach does not constrain the semantics of `ExitSuccess`, there is no associated algebraic law that pertains to every interpreter. It is possible to write interpreters that exit when encountering this instruction, but it is also possible to write interpreters that don't.

Of course, you can prove that any particular interpreter satisfies the law by inspection, for instance because it uses a wildcard pattern match. Sjoerd Visscher observes that you can also enforce this in the type system by changing the return type of `ExitSuccess` to `Void`. However, this doesn't work for other laws that can be baked into free monads, for instance the distributive law for the `mplus` instruction.

Thus, in a confusing turn of events, the operational approach is more free than the free monad, if you interpret "free" as "the least amount of algebraic laws".

It also means that these data types are not isomorphic. However, they are equivalent: every interpreter written with `Free` can be transformed into an interpreter written with `Program` and vice versa.

Personally, I like to put all of my laws into the interpreter, because there are a lot of laws that *cannot* be baked into the free monad, and I like to have them all in one place.

Comment: You can also point out that the law for `Free` is independent of the observation function.  It's actually just `exitSuccess >>= f = exitSuccess`.

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to emphasize the point that laws don't need to hold until you apply `interpret`. A law is true iff there is no observation that can falsify it.

Comment: Right.  I just meant that you could use that to drive home that `Free` bakes certain laws into the type instead of the interpreter.

Comment: "However, this doesn't work for other laws that can be baked into free monads, for instance the distributive law for the mplus instruction." Can you expand on that?

Comment: @GavinWahl I meant that the distributive law cannot be baked into a monad built from `operational` via the type system, in contrast to the nice trick that is possible with `ExitSuccess`.

Comment: How do you do it with the Free monad?

Comment: @GavinWahl For example `data FooF k = MZero | MPlus k k` and `type MyMonad a = Free FooF a`. Then, the free monad will automatically satisfy `mplus a b >>= k = mplus (a >>= k) (b >>= k)`, whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is yes, but only if you use a different translation of `TeletypeF`:

```
data TeletypeI a where
    PutStrLn :: String -> TeletypeI ()
    GetLine :: TeletypeI String
    ExitSuccess :: TeletypeI Void
```

The argument of `TeletypeI` is what the operation will/must provide to the rest of the program. It is the type of the argument of the continuation `k` in

```
eval (ExitSuccess :>>= k) = ...
```

Since there are no values of type `Void`, we can be sure that `k` will never be called. (As always we'll have to ignore `undefined` here.)

An equivalent type is:

```
data TeletypeI a where
    PutStrLn :: String -> TeletypeI ()
    GetLine :: TeletypeI String
    ExitSuccess :: TeletypeI a
```

Now we would have to provide a value to `k` that matches any type, and we can't do that either. This can be more practical since `singleton ExitSuccess` now has the flexible type `Program TeletypeI a`.

Similarly, `exitSuccess` could be fixed by giving it the type `IO Void`, or `IO a`.

Comment: "As always we'll have to ignore `undefined` here" - you don't have to ignore `undefined` with the `TeletypeF` formulation in order to make the guarantee. This is why "the answer is no" and "the answer is yes" are both correct. :)

Comment: I'm sure `undefined` can mess up the proof for `TeletypeF` as well, you just have to be a bit more devious.

Comment: Yes, both your answers would seem to be correct, and SO only lets me choose one accepted answer right?  Although you both missed my question about laziness, but I guess I shouldn't ask two questions in one post. :-)  Thank you both for your answers anyway.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher As Heinrich and Gabriel pointed out, using the `FreeT` monad instance guarantees that `exitSuccess >>= k === exitSuccess`. I don't see how `undefined` can possibly mess that up.

Comment: @DanBurton Define `run (Free ExitSuccess) = loop where loop = loop` for example.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, you cannot prove that the operational one ignores the rest of the program on `exitSuccess`. Contrast `TeletypeI` with `TeletypeF` to see why. I'll rewrite `TeletypeF` in GADT notation for easier comparison

```
data TeletypeF x where                     | data TeletypeI x where
  PutStrLn :: String -> x  -> TeletypeF x  |   PutStrLn :: String -> TeletypeI ()
  GetLine :: (String -> x) -> TeletypeF x  |   GetLine :: TeletypeI String
  ExitSuccess ::              TeletypeF x  |   ExitSuccess :: TeletypeI ()
```

Using `TeletypeF`, we can build actual programs right away:

```
GetLine (\str -> PutStrLn (map toUpper str) ExitSuccess)
```

`TeletypeI` does not come with a way to refer to "the rest of the program" in the same way that `TeletypeF` does.

```
-- TeletypeF:
GetLine (\str -> "rest of program" goes here)
-- or
PutStrLn someString ("rest of program" goes here)
-- or
ExitSuccess -- there is no "rest of program" slot provided
```

Since `TeletypeI` lacks this "rest of the program" information, you can no longer gain any knowledge when you come across `ExitSuccess`.

```
-- TeletypeI
PutStrLn someString -- no information about "rest of program"
-- or
GetLine -- no information about "rest of program"
-- or
ExitSuccess -- no information about "rest of program"
```

What is permissible to come as the "rest of the program" is entirely up to the `Program` type, which doesn't know anything about the instruction set it is being applied to. It simply allows you to bind instructions together, and terminate via `Return`.

Comment: Does your answer also imply that we don't lose laziness with the free monad version?  I guess I should try writing a free state monad to see for myself, though I'd have to figure out a translation for the `state` function...

Comment: @Dag it practically writes itself: http://hpaste.org/80607 . Are you implying that the `operational` approach loses laziness? I don't see how that is the case. (The `state` function is easily written in terms of `get` and `put`).

Comment: Consider the example at the bottom of my post, from the operational monad tutorial.  It evaluates to an infinite list that you can for example `take 10` from, no problem with mtl/transformers.  With operational and free, it hangs.  So unless I'm doing something wrong, I've answered my own question: yes, the free monad suffers the same laziness issue as operational.